# VS 2003: service pack installation confirmation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2003

How do I confirm that SP1 for Visual studio 2003 is installed on my machine. My About box in VS2003 dev environment shows SP1 for MS .net framework 1.1? How do I confirm for VS2003?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Help -> About, it should be listed in the Installed Products:

```
"Microsoft Visual Studio .NET 2003 Service Pack 1 (KB918007)"
```